# Array multi-dimensional error PHP

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php 
   $ctr = 0;
   foreach($rows as $row){
?>
   <input type="hidden" name="client<?php echo $ctr; ?>['client_id']" value="<?php echo $row['client_id']; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="client<?php echo $ctr; ?>['transaction_id']" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> 
   <input style="max-width: 100px;min-width:100px;" class="form-control right" type="text" name="client<?php echo $ctr;?>['amount']" value="" />
<?php 
    }
?>
```

Update: I have included the form where $_POST coming from.

This it the output of `print_r ($_POST);`:

```
Array
(
    [client0] => Array
        (
            ['client_id'] => 1
            ['transaction_id'] => 1
            ['amount'] => 1000
            ['mode'] => cash
        )

    [client1] => Array
        (
            ['client_id'] => 2
            ['transaction_id'] => 5
            ['amount'] => 600
            ['mode'] => cash
        )

    [client2] => Array
        (
            ['client_id'] => 3
            ['transaction_id'] => 6
            ['amount'] => 200
            ['mode'] => cash
        )

    [save] => 
)
```

When I try writing this: `echo $_POST['client0']['amount'];`.

I'm expecting an output of `1000`

but it gives me an error like this: `Notice: Undefined index: amount`.

So guys can you please tell me whats wrong with my code.TIA

Comment: `echo $_POST['client0']['amount'];` this is d correct one not amount_id

Comment: you dont' have any amount_id ni your array

Comment: You tried to use `amount_id` key, but undefined is `amount`? Check the key, if in array is amount or amount_id and then what you try to echo.

Comment: i have updated my question. tnx

Comment: where is the supposed HTML form with this, add this as well

Comment: `echo $_POST['client0']["'amount'"];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the `print_r` output carefully. One key is given as `client0` while the next is given as `'amount'`. That's because your key is actually `'amount'`, not `amount`. Because you're including unnecessary quotes in your HTML. Fix your HTML so the input name becomes:

```
name="client0[amount]"
```

(Or alternatively address the key as `$_POST['client0']["'amount'"]`.)

---

And while you're at it, you may want to rename your fields to:

```
name="clients[0][amount]"
```

Because then you can simply traverse the data using:

```
foreach ($_POST['clients'] as $client) {
    echo $client['id'], $client['amount'], ..;
}
```

Which is much more readable and sane.

Comment: it worked and i also followed your suggestion. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
echo $_POST['client0']['amount'];
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong variable amount_id just check it out your array having variable is "amount" so change the variable name like bellow

```
echo $_POST['client0']['amount'];
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: @christopherDesiderio : can you just tell what you are returning like mysql_query_array() ..etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this way ..

```
foreach ($_POST['client0'] as $val) {
        echo $val['amount'] ;
    }
```

Comment: this should not help him as `$_POST['client0']['amount']` itself is no array.